# difference between mongodb and mongodb-server

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

When I am trying to install mongodb in my Ubuntu box, apt-get shows me the following options

> mongodb          mongodb-clients  mongodb-dev      mongodb-server

Can anyone please tell me the difference between mongodb and mongodb-server?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Package [mongodb](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/amd64/mongodb/filelist) installs full set of packages - client, admin tools, development files, mongod (mongodb daemon) and mongos (shard routing service), while [mongodb-server](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/amd64/mongodb-server/filelist) installs only mongod and mongos (and logs / docs).